# Which are the Best sites to Learn Spoken English"?

Tags: idioms, speech

What are some sites which have great material to learn idioms , phrases and new words. I want to improve my spoken English skills!

Comment: One of them is another site on StackExchange, which I think would be more fun and helpful to you: [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for websites for learning English, not about the English language itself.

Comment: [www.letsalive.com](http://letsalive.com) .. here you can talk to the people who also have the same interest. You can connect through skype.